# Only need simple_format when there are is new line \n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, formatting, carriage-return, helpermethods

I have some strings that contain carriage return (new lines), and using the helper method [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) works perfect for that.

Unfortunately though, now all strings get the wrapping tag and class defined with `simple_format`, and that creates unwanted styling for strings that don't contain carriage return.

Is there any way to get the benefits of `simple_format` only when needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_string.include?("\n") ? simple_format(my_string) : my_string
```